# QML binding: UI updated only when exiting the function

Tags: c++, qt, qml

Qt 5.15.10 on Buildroot 2023.08-rc3.

**main.cpp**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);   
    MyClass myclass;

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated, &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl)
    {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl) QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);

    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("myclass", &myclass);
    engine.load(url);

    QTimer::singleShot(0, &myclass, &MyClass::load);
    return app.exec();
}
```

**myclass.h**

```
class MyClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(qreal progress READ progress WRITE setProgress NOTIFY progressChanged)

public:
    explicit MyClass(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    ~MyClass();

    qreal progress() { return _progress; }
    void setProgress(qreal value)
    {
        if (_progress != value)
        {
            _progress = value;
            emit progressChanged(value);
        }
    }

private:
    qreal _progress;

public slots:
    void load();

signals:
    void progressChanged(qreal value);
};
```

**myclass.cpp**

```
void MyClass::load()
{
    QDir dir(MY_PATH);
    QFileInfoList files = dir.entryInfoList(QStringList() << "*.dat", QDir::Files);

    int i = 0;
    foreach(QFileInfo file, files)
    {
        // .. do something: it takes about 1-2 seconds
        qreal progress = static_cast<qreal>(++i) / files.size();
        setProgress(progress);
    }
}
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15

Window {
    id: root
    visible: true
    visibility: Window.FullScreen
    color: "black"

    Loading {
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
    }
}
```

**Loading.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

Rectangle {
    property double value: myclass.progress

    id: control
    color: "gray"
    border.width: 1
    border.color: "white"
    height: 20
    anchors.margins: 20

    Rectangle {
        anchors.left: control.left
        anchors.bottom: control.bottom
        height: control.height
        width: control.width * control.value
        color: "lime"
    }
}
```

I put several `console.log()` statements and I confirm that the `value` and the `width` are correctly updated while the `foreach` loop runs.

The problem is on the screen see only the 100% state, that is then the `foreach` loop has finished. I can easily see all the intermediate steps in the console, since each iteration takes at least 1-2 seconds.

What does prevent the UI to update every time the property changes and the related signal is emitted?

Comment: I assume it's because your for-loop is blocking the UI thread.

Comment: If you never return control back to the event loop, the UI can't update.

Comment: Yeah. I thought it didn't block since the signals were delivered to the QML

Comment: I suggest doing the for-loop in a separate worker thread, and just report back the results to the main thread using signals.